# How to extract only Hour data from PHP Time string?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a collection of time records in a database in the format '09:51:06' (hour, minute, second).

I have a query which retrieves a bunch of these times from the database, but I only care for the Hour reference.

How can I get rid of the rest of the string and ad just the hour into an array? So in the example above, I just want to keep '09'.

I've looked into exploding and substrings, but can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: What data type is that column?

Comment: Never, ever record date in a database as a string: it takes more byte and its harder to manage and you easily get stuck in problem like this one. Use timestamp format, so you will be able to use date() or other function and get whatever you want as easily as php make it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exploding the string would look like this (you probably want to add `intval()` to be able to use it as a real number):

```
$hours = array_shift(explode(':', '09:51:06'));
```

But you are probably looking for the right query instead of doing this afterwards. If you are dealing with a time-type, you can use MySQL's [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) (`HOUR()` in this case):

```
SELECT HOUR(`time_column`) AS `hour` FROM `your_table`
```

Comment: I agree with the database solution. But if you must do it with code, a `$h = substr($time, 0, 2)` is trivial.

Comment: I've not come across that SQL before, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This will break: `$hours = array_shift(explode(':', '09:51:06'));` because you cannot pass a function result directly to another function (`array_shift()` in this case) that receives its arguments by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Or from the database itself

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(field_name, '%H') as return_hour from table_name
```

Comment: Could be re-written as just `SELECT HOUR(field_name) ...` as well. Makes it a bit more explicit as to what you're selecting, without having to remember all the format string characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$time_string='09:51:06';
$your_array[$array_index]=substr($time_string, 0, 2);
```

[for more info on substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this either thru string manipulation or time/date. Any worthwhile date way would be on the SQL side, PHP has mktime and date functions but you would have get the hour you're looking for intermediately along the way if you were to construct a date anyway

String

```
$thisHour = array_shift(explode(':', $timeString));  //this gets hour
$thisHour - substr($timeString, 0, 2);              // or this
$hours[] = $thisHour;                               //this adds to array
```